# In a string list how to split by every 2 character and insert a comma

Tags: c#

I have a list string which has values like below, could you please let me know how to split the list by every 2 character and insert a comma separated and assign the final list to another list.

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {"DVMNKL"};
var list2 = new List<string>() {"DV","MN","KL"};
```

Some time `list1` can have only 2 character, at that time I should not split, I have to just assign to `list2`

Comment: Your example will not compile so it is hard to understand what's your aim is. Also please add a code you already tried - we don't want to post duplicated code you already worked with.

Comment: So, say `list1` contains two 5 character strings. Are we expecting `list2` to contain five 2 character strings, or two 2-chars, a 1-char, two 2-chars and a 1-char?

Comment: sir, its not duplicate can you please help me

Comment: list1 can contains any even number of characters like 2,4 6 8 10 etc..

Comment: But it's a *list*. So are you saying it will only ever contain exactly one string, and that will have an even length, or what?

Comment: yes, this list1 may contain at least 2 character always, or may be more then 2 like 2,4,6,8 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Linq` to manage that.

```
int splitByCount = 2;
string s = new List<string> { "DVMNLS", "DVMNLS" };

var split = s.SelectMant(c => c) //flatten the list of strings to IEnumerable<char>
    .Select((c, index) => new {c, index})
    .GroupBy(x => x.index/splitByCount)
    .Select(group => group.Select(elem => elem.c))
    .Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", split));
```

the output

```
DV,MN,KL,DV,MN,KL
```

Comment: thanks you for the response, but in your example you have taken as  string s = "DVMNLS";, but mine is list<string>, so will it work fine

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me a lot